# Automatic Conversion to Specific Date Format in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

Each time I enter 6/1988 in an Excel 2010 cell and press Enter, or select other cell, that entry, 6/1988 changes to Jun-88. I want to keep that entry as 6/1988. Even if I choose general formatting for that cell, or even the column, the entry changes to Jun-88.

How can I prevent it not to change to date format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting a single quote in front:

'6/1998